# Exclude file from "isolated modules" in tsconfig.json

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm building a node.js application using `worker_threads` under the hood. In the script file, called `worker.ts`, I cannot use the import statement because Node throws an error. So I'm importing the needed packages like this:

```
const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads')

parentPort.on('message', (data) => {
    //Non relevant code
})
```

However, despite the code actually working, the following error is displayed since there is neither an import nor an export statement:

```
'worker.ts' cannot be compiled under '--isolatedModules' because it is considered a global script file.
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: "_I cannot use the import statement because Node throws an error_": What does this mean? Also, you can use `export {};` in any script to make TS recognize it as a module. [This](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzmAhlApgOxgBWvAXzgDMoIQ4ByAd2gGt0oB9GACwxQBMBnSgbgCwAKGGoM2PLAD8AOgiYAFJRDpu3FAHN0lADRwFnFDBQBKOAF4AfIgInBQoA) is how you can import it with ESM.

Comment: The worker is not executed as a module. So it throws `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. Adding an empty export is just a "workaround",  I'd like to know if there is a proper way of handling worker scripts with TS.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (meaning all files needed to reproduce: `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`, all modules, etc.)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-lewin-iu3noh?file=/src/worker.ts Open it using VScode. CodeSandbox doesn't show the error related to the tsconfig.

Comment: The link you shared doesn't include any other source files besides the worker module. If I exchange the `require` statement for `import` (or simply include an empty export statement as I [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204389/exclude-file-from-isolated-modules-in-tsconfig-json?noredirect=1#comment125862933_71204389) above, compilation is successful. Can you elaborate on what the actual issue is? If you are facing a runtime issue, you'll need to provide some code to demonstrate what the problem is.

Comment: @jsejcksn I have added a main.ts to make the whole thing executable. Now, if you run the main, the code will work despite the error shown by VScode. However, if you exchange `require` with `import` the error disappears but the code will stop working.

Comment: Before I experiment further with your project configuration: is there a reason that you are using CommonJS module format (legacy) in your project rather than ESM (current standard)?

Comment: @jsejcksn I'm building a library for a node.js application that wraps and simplifies an API that I need to upload on npm later on.

Comment: I'm not sure how the relates to the question that I asked: Node supports using ESM and you can publish npm packages in ESM format. Using ESM is the right way forward for all module code (unless you're working in some kind of legacy codebase that depends on an old version of Node). I provided an answer that explains what to change to get a successful compilation and runtime result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [CodeSandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-lewin-iu3noh?file=/src/worker.ts) that [you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204389/exclude-file-from-isolated-modules-in-tsconfig-json?noredirect=1#comment125864635_71204389) as a reference, I'll explain the changes that need to be made in both TypeScript modules in order for compilation to succeed and for the program to execute successfully:

`./src/index.ts`:

```ts
// Use import statements: TypeScript will transform them into "require" calls
// because you are targeting CommonJS in your TSConfig
import {Worker} from 'worker_threads';
import * as path from 'path';

const worker = new Worker(path.resolve(__dirname, './worker.js'));
/*                                                         ^^^
                      It is important to use the path of the **COMPILED** file,
                      and the extension of the compiled file will be ".js"    */
worker.on('message', (data) => console.log('Main: ' + data));
worker.postMessage('Hello!');
```

`./src/worker.ts`:

```ts
// Again, use import statement
import {parentPort} from 'worker_threads';

parentPort.on('message', (data) => {
  console.log('Worker: ' + data);
  setTimeout(() => parentPort.postMessage(data), 1000);
});
```

Run:

```
# $ cd path/to/project/dir
$ tsc && node dist/index.js
Worker: Hello!
Main: Hello!
```